# pandasでuniqueを使用したいのですが、Dataframeでしか取り出せないためどうすればいいのか分かりません。

Tags: python, pandas

pandasでuniqueを使用したいのですが、Dataframeでしか取り出せないためどうすればいいのか分かりません。

pandasで読み込んでいるデータ(df)

```
    a   b
    -0.2    -0.200
    -0.2    -0.195
    -0.2    -0.190
    -0.2    -0.185
    -0.2    -0.180
```

列名に関係なく取り出したいため、`df.iloc[:,[0]]`でデータを取り出しています。この取り出したデータに対して`unique`を使いたいです。
しかし、`df.iloc[:,[0]]`の場合、Dataframeでしか取り出せないため、`df.iloc[:,[0]].unique`としたいのですが、`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'`となり、うまく実行することが出来ません。どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)の感じがします。元々のDataFrameの例と、そこから取得したいデータの形式・内容、現在のソースコードと問題のある処理結果等を他の人が簡単に再現・調査出来るような形で記述してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 欲しい結果が分かりません。欲しい結果はどんな型でどんなものが欲しいのでしょうか？ また、「うまく実行することが出来ません」とはどういう状況を表しているのでしょうか？

Comment: @asdfe さん、`uniqueを使用したい`というのは中間的な処理であって、実際にunique相当の機能を適用するとしても、(unique処理をした結果の)最終的に取得したいデータは何で、それはDataFrameの何処から導き出されるものか？ といった事を追記してみてください。つまり`df.iloc[:,[0]].unique`はそのままの形では実行できないだろうから他の処理で置き換えるということです。

Answer (score 1):

カラムから pandas.Series取り出すにはいくつか方法があります

- `df['a']`
- `df.a`
- `df[df.columns[0]]`
- `df.iloc[:, 0])`

`df.iloc[:,[0]]` ではリスト指定なので結果は DataFrame

```py
df[df.columns[0]].unique()

# array([-0.2])
```

Answer (score 1):

御質問が多少分かり難いので的外れかもしれませんが，データフレームの要素からユニークな要素の配列を得る方法を回答します。
（追記）`.values` は非推奨なので，`.to_numpy()` に変更しました。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[-0.2, -0.200], [-0.2, -0.195],
                   [-0.2, -0.190], [-0.2, -0.185],
                   [-0.2, -0.180]], columns=['a', 'b'])

u1 = np.unique(df.iloc[:, [0]].to_numpy())  # original example
u2 = np.unique(df.to_numpy())               # all elements

print(u1); print(u2)
```

```
[-0.2]
[-0.2   -0.195 -0.19  -0.185 -0.18 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.iloc[:,0].unique())` とする方がよいかと思うのですが、あくまでも `pandas.DataFrame` 型に拘るのあれば `pd.DataFrame.apply()` メソッドを使う方法があります。ただ、この場合は出力も `pandas.DataFrame` 型になります。

```py
print(df.iloc[:, [0]].apply(pd.Series.unique))
print(df.iloc[:, [1]].apply(pd.Series.unique))

#      a
# 0 -0.2
#
#        b
# 0 -0.200
# 1 -0.195
# 2 -0.190
# 3 -0.185
# 4 -0.180
```